# Grouped routes not working with filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to get my filters to work with my grouped routes. No matter what I try I am always able to access the route when im not suppose to. I'm still a bit new to laravel and I can't figure this out why it wont work.

Here is the route

```php
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'bf4'), function()
{
    Route::get('scoreboard', 'HomeController@bf4scoreboard');
    Route::get('playerinfo/{id}', 'PlayerController@bf4info')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');
    Route::post('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');

    // Only users with the permission to view the battlefield 4 admin section are allowed
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'bf4_admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('records', 'BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords');
    });
});
```

Here is the filter

```php
Route::filter('bf4_admin', function()
{
    if(!Entrust::can('viewbf4admin'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});
```

Problem is it will always allow me to view that page when it shouldn't as I don't have the permission to view it on the user role.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 1

Here is the full routes file. Its messy but will be cleaned up later.

```php
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('error.404');
});

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::view('error.404');
});

Route::resource('upload', 'FileController');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user'), function()
{
    Route::post('/create', 'UserController@store');
    Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login');
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@do_login');
    Route::get('/confirm/{code}', 'UserController@confirm');
    Route::post('/forgot_password', 'UserController@do_forgot_password');
    Route::get('/reset_password/{token}', 'UserController@reset_password');
    Route::post('/reset_password', 'UserController@do_reset_password');
    Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('user/profile/{username?}', 'UserController@show_profile');
    //Route::get('/profile/{name?}', 'UserController@show_profile');
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'UserController@edit_profile');
});

// Begin API Route
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    // General Battlefield Routes
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}/chat', function($id)
        {
            $isBF4 = (DB::table('tbl_server')->join('tbl_games', 'tbl_server.GameID', '=', 'tbl_games.GameID')->where('ServerID', $id)->pluck('Name') == 'BF4') ? TRUE : FALSE;
            return Response::json(Helper::getServerChatScoreboard($id, $isBF4));
        });

        Route::post('adminReports', array('before' => 'auth'), function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::getAdminReports());
        });

        Route::post('playerSearch/{name?}', function($name = FALSE)
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::searchForPlayer($name));
        });

        Route::get('playerInfo/{id?}', function($playerid = FALSE)
        {
            $info = Helper::buildPlayerProfile($playerid);

            if(isset($info['status']) && $info['status'] == 'error') return Response::json($info, 404);

            return Response::json($info);

        })->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    });


    // Battlefield 3 Specific Routes
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield/3'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf3Scoreboard;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::post('scoreboard/{id}/admin', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf3Admin;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::get('population', function()
        {
            $gameid = DB::table('tbl_games')->where('Name', 'BF3')->pluck('GameID');
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchServerPopulation($gameid));
        });
    });

    Route::post('bf3/admin_reports', function()
    {
        return Response::json(array('status' => 'success'));
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield/4'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf4Scoreboard;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::post('scoreboard/{id}/admin', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf4Admin;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::get('premessage', function()
        {
            return Helper::fetchPreMessages(Input::get('id'));
        });

        Route::get('population', function()
        {
            $gameid = DB::table('tbl_games')->where('Name', 'BF4')->pluck('GameID');
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchServerPopulation($gameid));
        });
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'common'), function()
    {
        Route::post('adminReports', function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::getAdminReports());
        });

        Route::get('/repofeed', function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchRepoActivity());
        });
    });
});
// End API Route

// Begin Page Route
Route::get('install', 'SetupController@install');
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
});

Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'bf4'), function()
{
    Route::get('scoreboard', 'HomeController@bf4scoreboard');
    Route::get('playerinfo/{id}', 'PlayerController@bf4info')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');
    Route::post('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');

    // Only users with the permission to view the battlefield 4 admin section are allowed
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'bf4_admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('records', 'BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords');
    });
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'bf3'), function()
{
    Route::get('scoreboard', 'HomeController@bf3scoreboard');
    Route::get('playerinfo/{id}', 'PlayerController@bf3info')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf3');
    Route::post('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf3');
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'bf3_admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('records', 'BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords');
    });
});

Route::when('admin/*', 'site_admin');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('memberlist', 'AdminController@memberList');
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'AdminController@showuser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('user/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edituser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::post('user/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@do_edituser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
});

// End Page Route
```

Comment: Are those `ALL` your routes? Other routes could be biasing any of those.

Comment: No its not all my routes. I'll update my question with the full routes if thats what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. I copied everything to my routes file and did some changes just to ignore Entrust and show a `denied` message in the filter:

Hitting http://server.dev/site/bf4/admin/records gives me `denied`. So the filter is working and redirection also worked, I just removed it to see a clear message.

Copy this all to your routes files and try the same. If it doesn't work, you might have a problem somewhere else:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('error.404');
});

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::view('error.404');
});

Route::filter('bf4_admin', function()
{
        return 'denied';
});

Route::resource('upload', 'FileController');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user'), function()
{
    Route::post('/create', 'UserController@store');
    Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login');
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@do_login');
    Route::get('/confirm/{code}', 'UserController@confirm');
    Route::post('/forgot_password', 'UserController@do_forgot_password');
    Route::get('/reset_password/{token}', 'UserController@reset_password');
    Route::post('/reset_password', 'UserController@do_reset_password');
    Route::get('/logout', 'UserController@logout');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('user/profile/{username?}', 'UserController@show_profile');
    //Route::get('/profile/{name?}', 'UserController@show_profile');
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'UserController@edit_profile');
});

// Begin API Route
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    // General Battlefield Routes
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}/chat', function($id)
        {
            $isBF4 = (DB::table('tbl_server')->join('tbl_games', 'tbl_server.GameID', '=', 'tbl_games.GameID')->where('ServerID', $id)->pluck('Name') == 'BF4') ? TRUE : FALSE;
            return Response::json(Helper::getServerChatScoreboard($id, $isBF4));
        });

        Route::post('adminReports', array('before' => 'auth'), function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::getAdminReports());
        });

        Route::post('playerSearch/{name?}', function($name = FALSE)
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::searchForPlayer($name));
        });

        Route::get('playerInfo/{id?}', function($playerid = FALSE)
        {
            $info = Helper::buildPlayerProfile($playerid);

            if(isset($info['status']) && $info['status'] == 'error') return Response::json($info, 404);

            return Response::json($info);

        })->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    });


    // Battlefield 3 Specific Routes
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield/3'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf3Scoreboard;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::post('scoreboard/{id}/admin', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf3Admin;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::get('population', function()
        {
            $gameid = DB::table('tbl_games')->where('Name', 'BF3')->pluck('GameID');
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchServerPopulation($gameid));
        });
    });

    Route::post('bf3/admin_reports', function()
    {
        return Response::json(array('status' => 'success'));
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'battlefield/4'), function()
    {
        Route::get('scoreboard/{id}', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf4Scoreboard;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::post('scoreboard/{id}/admin', function($id = NULL)
        {
            $b = new App\Models\Battlefield\Bf4Admin;
            return $b->initialize($id);
        });

        Route::get('premessage', function()
        {
            return Helper::fetchPreMessages(Input::get('id'));
        });

        Route::get('population', function()
        {
            $gameid = DB::table('tbl_games')->where('Name', 'BF4')->pluck('GameID');
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchServerPopulation($gameid));
        });
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'common'), function()
    {
        Route::post('adminReports', function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::getAdminReports());
        });

        Route::get('/repofeed', function()
        {
            return Response::json(Helper::fetchRepoActivity());
        });
    });
});
// End API Route

// Begin Page Route
Route::get('install', 'SetupController@install');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'home';
});

Route::get('dashboard', 'HomeController@index');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'bf4'), function()
{
    Route::get('scoreboard', 'HomeController@bf4scoreboard');
    Route::get('playerinfo/{id}', 'PlayerController@bf4info')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');
    Route::post('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf4');

    // Only users with the permission to view the battlefield 4 admin section are allowed
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'bf4_admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('records', 'BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords');
    });
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'bf3'), function()
{
    Route::get('scoreboard', 'HomeController@bf3scoreboard');
    Route::get('playerinfo/{id}', 'PlayerController@bf3info')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf3');
    Route::post('playersearch', 'PlayerController@searchbf3');
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'bf3_admin'), function()
    {
        Route::get('records', 'BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords');
    });
});

Route::when('admin/*', 'site_admin');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('memberlist', 'AdminController@memberList');
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'AdminController@showuser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::get('user/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edituser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::post('user/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@do_edituser')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
});


// +--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------+
// | Domain | URI                                          | Name                                         | Action                                      | Before Filters   | After Filters |
// +--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------+
// |        | GET upload                                   | upload.index                                 | FileController@index                        |                  |               |
// |        | GET upload/create                            | upload.create                                | FileController@create                       |                  |               |
// |        | POST upload                                  | upload.store                                 | FileController@store                        |                  |               |
// |        | GET upload/{upload}                          | upload.show                                  | FileController@show                         |                  |               |
// |        | GET upload/{upload}/edit                     | upload.edit                                  | FileController@edit                         |                  |               |
// |        | PUT upload/{upload}                          | upload.update                                | FileController@update                       |                  |               |
// |        | PATCH upload/{upload}                        |                                              | FileController@update                       |                  |               |
// |        | DELETE upload/{upload}                       | upload.destroy                               | FileController@destroy                      |                  |               |
// |        | POST user/create                             |                                              | UserController@store                        |                  |               |
// |        | GET user/login                               |                                              | UserController@login                        |                  |               |
// |        | POST user/login                              |                                              | UserController@do_login                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET user/confirm/{code}                      |                                              | UserController@confirm                      |                  |               |
// |        | POST user/forgot_password                    |                                              | UserController@do_forgot_password           |                  |               |
// |        | GET user/reset_password/{token}              |                                              | UserController@reset_password               |                  |               |
// |        | POST user/reset_password                     |                                              | UserController@do_reset_password            |                  |               |
// |        | GET user/logout                              |                                              | UserController@logout                       |                  |               |
// |        | GET user/profile/{username?}                 |                                              | UserController@show_profile                 | auth             |               |
// |        | GET profile/edit                             |                                              | UserController@edit_profile                 | auth             |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/scoreboard/{id}/chat     |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | POST api/battlefield/adminReports            |                                              | Closure                                     | auth             |               |
// |        | POST api/battlefield/playerSearch/{name?}    |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/playerInfo/{id?}         |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/3/scoreboard/{id}        |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | POST api/battlefield/3/scoreboard/{id}/admin |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/3/population             |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | POST api/bf3/admin_reports                   |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/4/scoreboard/{id}        |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | POST api/battlefield/4/scoreboard/{id}/admin |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/4/premessage             |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/battlefield/4/population             |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | POST api/common/adminReports                 |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET api/common/repofeed                      |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET install                                  |                                              | SetupController@install                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET /                                        |                                              | Closure                                     |                  |               |
// |        | GET dashboard                                |                                              | HomeController@index                        |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf4/scoreboard                           |                                              | HomeController@bf4scoreboard                |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf4/playerinfo/{id}                      |                                              | PlayerController@bf4info                    |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf4/playersearch                         |                                              | PlayerController@searchbf4                  |                  |               |
// |        | POST bf4/playersearch                        |                                              | PlayerController@searchbf4                  |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf4/admin/records                        |                                              | BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords | bf4_admin        |               |
// |        | GET bf3/scoreboard                           |                                              | HomeController@bf3scoreboard                |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf3/playerinfo/{id}                      |                                              | PlayerController@bf3info                    |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf3/playersearch                         |                                              | PlayerController@searchbf3                  |                  |               |
// |        | POST bf3/playersearch                        |                                              | PlayerController@searchbf3                  |                  |               |
// |        | GET bf3/admin/records                        |                                              | BattlefieldAdminController@showAdKatRecords | bf3_admin        |               |
// |        | GET admin/memberlist                         |                                              | AdminController@memberList                  | auth, site_admin |               |
// |        | GET admin/user/{id}                          |                                              | AdminController@showuser                    | auth, site_admin |               |
// |        | GET admin/user/{id}/edit                     |                                              | AdminController@edituser                    | auth, site_admin |               |
// |        | POST admin/user/{id}/edit                    |                                              | AdminController@do_edituser                 | auth, site_admin |               |
// +--------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thats odd. How come when the filter is in the routes file it works but when its in the actual filters file it doesn't?

Comment: Filters are loaded in `app/start/global.php`, is the request line present?

Comment: Yes, the require for it is present.